# Bash: make sum of numbers with corresponding name

Tags: bash

I have a file (sorted) that looks like this:

```
alma-court, 1, 0, 8
alma-court, 4, 2, 24
atlantic-house, 99, 1, 340
diamond, 2, 2, 16
iminds-zuiderpoort, 0, 1, 0
north-plaza, 18, 3, 718
north-plaza, 90, 2, 19
```

I'd like to make a vertical total for each identical first column.

So for alma-court, i'd like to get the total of 1+4, 0+2 and 8+24.
atlantic-house is already fine, as it's the only occurrence. 
And north-plaza should be 18+90, 3+2 and 718+19.

And printing everything like this:

```
alma-court, 5, 2, 32
atlantic-house, 99, 1, 340
...
```

Could someone give me the solution using Bash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
groups=( $( cut -d ',' -f 1 count.txt | sort -u ) )

for group in "${groups[@]}"
do
  grep $group count.txt | awk '{ sum1+=$2; sum2+=$3; sum3+=$4;} END {print $1 " " sum1 ", " sum2 ", " sum3}'
done

anew@buddha:~/dev/so$ bash so.sh 
alma-court, 5, 2, 32
atlantic-house, 99, 1, 340
diamond, 2, 2, 16
iminds-zuiderpoort, 0, 1, 0
north-plaza, 108, 5, 737
```

Comment: Be aware that if there are hundreds of names in the file and the file is thousands of lines long, this solution is going to make hundreds of passes through the file, which will be slow.  A better `awk` solution makes a single pass through the file (and uses no auxilliary processes), which leads to better performance if the data set is big.  On the sample data set, the difference is probably not quantifiable.

Comment: Note too that the `cat` is unnecessary ([UUOC Award](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html)), and that the use of `uniq` only works if, as in the sample data, all the related rows in a group are together in the file.  Using `cut -d ',' -f 1 count.txt | sort -u` avoids the UUOC and is reliable regardless of how the data is sorted.  Despite my prior 'non-quantifiable' comment, even on this size of data set, the `grep` solution is measurably (but not perceptibly) slower, at 24 ms (milliseconds) compared with 25 ms for `grep`+`sort`, 6 ms for `awk`, and 5 ms for `bash-4.2`.

Comment: Well stated. I was aware this solution uses multiple passes, hope the OP is aware; and the OP stated that the file was sorted, so I assumed some form of `sort` had been applied. I've removed the superfluous `cat`. +1 for the benchmarks, and calling me out on the UUOC Award :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as the basis of a `bash script`

```
set -u
tr -d "," < data2 | while read name col1 col2 col3 ; do
    echo name=$name col1=$col1 col2=$col2 col3=$col3
done
```

Where `data2` is your sorted file.

It gives out the following and from there you should be able to detect changes in 'name' and do the math.

```
name=alma-court col1=1 col2=0 col3=8
name=alma-court col1=4 col2=2 col3=24
name=atlantic-house col1=99 col2=1 col3=340
name=diamond col1=2 col2=2 col3=16
name=iminds-zuiderpoort col1=0 col2=1 col3=0
name=north-plaza col1=18 col2=3 col3=718
name=north-plaza col1=90 col2=2 col3=19
```

These things are usually done better in Perl/Python/Awk.

---

### EDIT added Perl version for completeness.

---

```
use strict;
my %names;
while(<>) {
    my @F = split(',');
    my $name = shift @F;
    foreach my $x (0..$#F) {
        $names{$name}[$x] += $F[$x];
    }
}
foreach my $key ( sort keys %names ){
    print $key, " ", join(" ", @{$names{$key}}), "\n";
}
```

Using as `perl myperl.pl < yourdata` gives

```
alma-court 5 2 32
atlantic-house 99 1 340
diamond 2 2 16
iminds-zuiderpoort 0 1 0
north-plaza 108 5 737
```

Comment: +1 for the 'better done in Perl/Python/Awk' comment — very true.

Comment: Awk could work. Perl and Python are not an option I'm afraid.

Comment: I was adding a Perl version then I saw your comment :( - @JonathanLeffler's Awk version should do you well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` (unless you know or want to learn Perl or Python):

```
awk '{ sum[$1,0] += $2; sum[$1,1] += $3; sum[$1,2] += $4; names[$1] = 1; }
     END { for (name in names)
               printf "%s %d, %d, %d\n", name, sum[name,0], sum[name,1], sum[name,2];
         }' <<EOF
alma-court, 1, 0, 8
alma-court, 4, 2, 24
atlantic-house, 99, 1, 340
diamond, 2, 2, 16
iminds-zuiderpoort, 0, 1, 0
north-plaza, 18, 3, 718
north-plaza, 90, 2, 19
EOF
```

Output:

```
iminds-zuiderpoort, 0, 1, 0
alma-court, 5, 2, 32
north-plaza, 108, 5, 737
atlantic-house, 99, 1, 340
diamond, 2, 2, 16
```

If you want the names in a specific order, sort the output.  Note that the name includes the trailing comma, so the print format doesn't add a comma after the name.

---

Pure `bash` (4.x) implementation

```
{
declare -A sum
declare -A names

IFS=,
while read name v1 v2 v3
do
    names[$name]="$name"
    ((sum[${name}1] += $v1))
    ((sum[${name}2] += $v2))
    ((sum[${name}3] += $v3))
done 

for name in "${names[@]}"
do
    printf "%s, %d, %d, %d\n" $name ${sum[${name}1]} ${sum[${name}2]} ${sum[${name}3]}
done
} <<EOF
alma-court, 1, 0, 8
alma-court, 4, 2, 24
atlantic-house, 99, 1, 340
diamond, 2, 2, 16
iminds-zuiderpoort, 0, 1, 0
north-plaza, 18, 3, 718
north-plaza, 90, 2, 19
EOF
```

Output:

```
diamond, 2, 2, 16
atlantic-house, 99, 1, 340
north-plaza, 108, 5, 737
alma-court, 5, 2, 32
iminds-zuiderpoort, 0, 1, 0
```

Fortunately, the output of the `awk` and the `bash` scripts are the same, give or take the sort order of the data.

The `bash` script is using associative arrays, which are a feature of `bash` 4.x that is not present in `bash` 3.x.

Comment: Nice solution, shame it's bleeding edge bash, still on 3.x